# ocLazyLoad para carregar controllers de uma SPA AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading

Olá, comunidade!

Gostaria de saber se é uma boa ideia usar [ocLazyLoad](https://oclazyload.readme.io/) para carregar os *controllers* de uma aplicação (Single Page Application - SPA) do [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/).

Eu estou usando [UI Router](https://ui-router.github.io/) no lugar de [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute).

O código que eu tenho funciona perfeitamente (no exemplo, está simplificado, só para efeitos de demonstração).

```js
'use strict';

var minhaAplicacao = angular.module('minhaAplicacao', ['oc.lazyLoad', 'ui.router']);

angular.module('minhaAplicacao').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'partials/home/home.html',
            data: {pageTitle: 'Home'},
            resolve: {
                service: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        serie: true,
                        files: [
                            'partials/home/home.controller.js'
                        ]
                    });
                }]
            }
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="minhaAplicacao">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title data-ng-bind="'GEOPS | ' + $state.current.data.pageTitle">GEOPS</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower/vendor/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ui-view></div>
        <script src="path/to/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="path/to/ocLazyLoad.js"></script>
        <script src="path/to/ui-router.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

A minha dúvida é quanto às implições dessa prática.

Está errado fazer o *lazyloading* de *controllers* AngularJS?

Existe algum problema de segurança ou de escalabilidade nesse tipo de prática?

Answer (score 2):

Bom isso vai do seu projeto, eu acho válido usar ele pra carregar os `controllers`, `services` e etc, quando por exemplo a sua aplicação tem de se adequar ao perfil do usuário. Exemplo: o perfil de usuário operador não enxerga mais do que 2 telas/rotas do seu `SPA`, então você carregará os `.js` necessários para ele trabalhar em vez de fazer ele carregar a aplicação inteira. Assim também evita que algum "super user" veja os `.js` carregados além do que ele tem acesso.

Answer (score 1):

Olá!

Eu uso o $ocLazyLoad para carregar scripts e plugins de terceiros conforme a necessidade. Inclusive criei um mecanismo de dependências desses plugins para baixar automático no **resolve** da rota. Para os arquivos do angular controllers, services, components... eu não uso $ocLazyLoad e sim os minimizo e separo por módulos. Questão de opção, não vejo problema.